# WebDAV server-side implementation in Tomcat

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, webdav

The Problem: The task I have is to build a basic WebDAV servlet which is linked to a local root folder. For now the servlet must support listing of the directories and GET, to get the desired file. All this must follow the WebDAV protocol. Also, implementation must be done in Java, under Tomcat preferably.

The context: Now so far, I have had very limited exposure to HTTP Servlets, Tomcat etc. which is why I find the task quite difficult. Although I understand how HTTP servlets work I do not understand how to make the transition from HTTP servlets to WebDAV servlets.

The approach: My idea was to extend the WebDAVServlet class (org.apache.catalina.servlets.WebdavServlet) and implement the doPropfind method and the doGet method. However, after reading the WebDAVServlet class, the methods seem to be implemented already. If that is the case, what can I use as a client to play around with the functionality (can I somehow send XML files which would represent HTTP requests, just for learning purposes?)? And then later, what should I extend in order to build the server I am required to read.

**In a nutshell**: If you had to build what I am required to build, how would you go about it? What class would you extend etc. Beginning the actual implementation I find is the hardest thing. If I were to see a very basic example of a WebDAV servlet, I believe I could build on top of that, but currently I am stuck, and ANY help will be appreciated, any resource, any link.

Thank you in advance and I apologize for the noob question.

Comment: _"If you had to build what I am required to build, how would you go about it?"_ - I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel. Can't you find an existing library / servlet that implements WebDAV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat provides WebDAV capabilities out of the box: you just have to configure them.

You should read the documentation for the [WebdavServlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/WebdavServlet.html).

If your requirement is to implement WebDAV... installing Tomcat and configuring it properly fulfills that requirement. There is no software development to be done unless Tomcat's WebdavServlet somehow does not meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was also stuck here. Here's what I did:
1) Created a new Dynamic Web Project in eclipse
2) Edited the web.xml and added what was required in the link
3) Exported the project as a war file, and I put it in the webapps folder
4) Tried to run it through apache and it says resource not available.
After that I plan to map the http://localhost/WebDAV as a WebFolder (in windows), but surely I've done something wrong earlier. Was I supposed just to edit the  web.xml in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf? Also, how do I point our which folder will be the 'repository'?

Comment: WebDAV is the name of my project btw (where I say that I will map localhost/WebDAV to a WebFolder). Again, than you for your patience, I realize that my questions are very stupid...

Comment: Do not edit `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml`: instead, edit the `web.xml` file in your own project. You cannot pick the directory that will be the "repository": the webapp itself becomes the repository. You might want to couple `WebdavServlet` with Tomcat 7's virtual path aliasing to see if you can mount a completely different directory.

Comment: For now will not complicate things, so I will leave the repository as it is. However, after following the instructions in the link you have provided, I tried to map the webapp folder to a WebFolder. So I went to My Network places, selected "Add Network Place" wrote http://localhost:8080/WebDAVTest/for the address, and I received the following message: "The folder you entered does not appear to be valid. Please choose another." Any thoughts on why this is happening? Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have updated with "Software Update for Web Folders (KB907306)" since it was suggested as being one of the causes of this error but this did not change anything in my case.

Comment: Also, if I use cadaver to access it I get the following response: $ cadaver http://localhost:8080/WebDAVTest
Could not access /WebDAVTest/ (not WebDAV-enabled?):
405 Method Not Allowed
Connection to `localhost' closed.
I've changed the name of the project to webdav and updated the web.xml, but still I get the same result.
And I get "The requested resource (/webdav) is not available." when I try to access http://localhost:8080/webdav through the browser

Comment: What is your client OS? Also, what (if any) kind of authentication are you using? Are you also using HTTPS?

Comment: My OS is Windows XP x86, I have tried both with authentication and without. When I use authentication and I try to run it in eclipse at least I get a pop-up asking me for my credentials (but they are never accepted, although I have added them in conf/tomcat-users.xml, by following the instructions in this link http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=uflu7dctjgancebb&number=1). When I do not use authentication I always get "The requested resource () is not available." I don't think I am using HTTPS, all my links are of type http://localhost/webdav/. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Microsoft Windows is a bit cranky about using WebDAV in general. On XP, I have gotten WebDAV to work over HTTPS with HTTP BASIC authentication by applying hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=907306. There is also a hotfix for Windows Vista (http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=907306) but once you get to Windows 7, you are out of luck when it comes to HTTP BASIC: Windows 7 will simply not do it. Instead, you need to use HTTP DIGEST which is a total PITA. We had to switch to using [Webdrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/download/index.html) to get it to work.

Comment: We want to use Tomcat WebDav implementation for our CMS needs, however instead of storing documents to filesystem we would like to stored them in the database.  Should I override the WebDavServlet implementation?

Comment: @PeterDelaney Join the Tomcat mailing list and ask there. Or, ask a new question on SO.